# Netbeans 7.0.1 doesn't start new line when pressed enter

Tags: netbeans

04, and when I open my php project and Scan completes a bar appears with "Please wait..." written on it. As I understood from reading forums etc that's the problem with the enter key.

Comment: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=268719#c14 is what helped me.

Comment: Back again, and this time using NetBeans 11.3-beta2 I found my comment above confusing. Clarification: https://askubuntu.com/a/1217843/48214

Answer (score 15):

I use netbeans 7.0.1 on debian and fixed the issue by klicking on the info icon left to the <?php and then selecting "Change project default to HTML 4.01 Transitional"

It seems that the default is HTML 5 - and this generates a parser Exception.
After switching the project default to the above mentioned setting I could use ENTER as normal - even on newly opened files.

Comment: thanks a lot , amazing how this can be related to such a thing as the html parser

Comment: I can't make the project, so how to write <?php and then project setting ....I'm also using netbeans 7.0.1 in debian

Comment: Doesn't work for me in NetBeans 8.2 with Blade PHP templates.

Answer (score 0):

i'Ve just install an upgrade of ubuntu and therefore netbeans.. I have to say, this upgrade was a lot of work.

On the 1st run of netbeans i got:

> cannot find an htmlParser implementation for HTML5

after a search i've decided to:

1. download an install the latest version from http://netbeans.org/downloads,
2. followed the instructions here,
   http://netbeans.org/community/releases/71/install.html
3. After the installation wizard i imported my settings from 7.0 and everything is smooth again.

-To run the install file use sh [filename]
-I saw somewhere that if you install using sudo, you will install for all users. can someone confirm that?

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: When I add the line `DOCTYPE` tag the editor automatically accepts <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key again, try adding this at the top of the file and when done editing you can remove it:

```
<\!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Comment: This is basically the same as the [answer by Croydon](http://askubuntu.com/a/139416/88802), right?

Comment: This did not work for me (using NetBeans 11.3-beta2 and Laravel Blade layout app.blade.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the icon displaying the error and changing to 4.1 STRICT

The best way is to update the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Please click on the Info (Bulb icon) on the top of the file or from where you start PHP code. After click on the bulb select “Change project default to HTML 4.01 Transitional” option and now you are able to use Enter key normally.

Please check the screenshot attached below.

[image]

Or check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449177/enter-key-does-not-work-on-netbeans-7-1/46538052#46538052

Answer (score 0):

### Here is the solution that has worked for me across multiple years and versions of NetBeans.

(Currently I'm using NetBeans 11.3-beta2.)

1. NetBeans > Tools > Plugins > Installed > Show Details
2. Sort by Name
3. Select "AngularJS Editor" and "Knockout HTML Editor" if they appear and are active.
4. Deactivate
5. Restart NetBeans.

Thanks to the [people before Comment #14 in 2018-11-15](https://bz.apache.org/netbeans/show_bug.cgi?id=268719#c14).

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I got the same problem with Netbeans 16 and 21. So...

As far as I have seen with Laravel projects, comments in blades (`{{-- ... --}}`) trigger strange behaviors, such as preventing new lines or even inserting tabs.

Strangely this doesn't always seem to happen, I think it is related to other Laravel code in the comment.

Removing them restores normal behavior.